# Lync 2010 event monitoring and call control API

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010

My objective is to listen to all the events (im/video/audio/appshare call, presence) of Lync server 2010 and also to control (transfer, conference, record) the call.

If we use UCMA to do the same, the call must first come to the application and from there routing is done. Basically here we are acting as Back2Back user agent.

I dont want to dot this. What I want is just listen to all events using some socket/API to get the events and send some commands to control the call. (Like how we do it with AVAYA using TSAPI or in FreeSwitch)

Comment: Depending on how "complex" your routing is, you could do it from `MSPL` directly, or put a `Dispatch()` in there to catch the messages and set their routing using some proper code.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.codelync.com/an-overview-of-the-lync-apis/) is a great summary of the all the different APIs available to you.

Hopefully, after reading that you'll be able to answer your own question, and see why Willem Duncan is suggesting using the Lync Server API as a way of capturing all the information you need.

Don't forget that your solution may be best realised in more than one application. For instance, you could start by writing the monitoring stuff first, using the Server API, and then create a UCMA application to do the recording. You can then route calls you want recorded to this.

Also, I believe there are commercial call recording solutions for Lync out there, if you're just looking for something that works.